# I need to create a custom print invoice.It should generate Xlsx

Tags: magento2, invoice, print

I need to create a custom print invoice.So i created a file `Export.php` in `module_sales->controller->adminhtml->invoice->Export.php`. Excel is generating but how to put the data into different cells where ever i want.Now i am getting the data in top column only (like A1,B1,C1,D1)Please help.

```
namespace Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Invoice;

use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\ExportInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;
use \Magento\Sales\Model\SalesInvoiceFactory;
use \Magento\Sales\Model\SalesOrderFactory;
use \Magento\Sales\Model\SalesInvoiceGridFactory;
use \Magento\Backend\App\Action;

class Export extends Action {

    protected $_salesinvoiceFactory;
    protected $_salesorderFactory;
    protected $_salesinvoicegridFactory;

    public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context, \Magento\Sales\Model\SalesInvoiceFactory $SalesInvoiceFactory, \Magento\Sales\Model\SalesOrderFactory $SalesOrderFactory, \Magento\Sales\Model\SalesInvoiceGridFactory $SalesInvoiceGridFactory
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);

        $this->_salesinvoiceFactory = $SalesInvoiceFactory;
        $this->_salesorderFactory = $SalesOrderFactory;
        $this->_salesinvoicegridFactory = $SalesInvoiceGridFactory;
    }

    public function execute() {
        $rows = array();
        $invoiceId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('invoice_id');
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $invoicemodel = $this->_salesinvoiceFactory->create()->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', $invoiceId);
        foreach ($invoicemodel as $invoice) {

            $invoiceno = $invoice['increment_id'];
        }

        $ordermodel = $this->_salesorderFactory->create()->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', $invoiceId);

        foreach ($ordermodel as $order) {
            $invoiceno = $order['invoice_number'];

            $issueofinvoice = $order['created_at'];
            array_push($rows, $issueofinvoice);
            $timeofinvoice = $order['created_at'];
            array_push($rows, $timeofinvoice);
            $dispatchmethod = $order['dispatch_method'];
            array_push($rows, $dispatchmethod);
            $grandtotal = $order['grand_total'];
            array_push($rows, $grandtotal);
        }

        $gridmodel = $this->_salesinvoicegridFactory->create()->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', $invoiceId);
        foreach ($gridmodel as $grid) {

            $nameandaddress = $grid['billing_address'];
            array_push($rows, $nameandaddress);
        }

        header('Content-Type: text/xls; charset=utf-8');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=klauz.xls');

        // create a file pointer connected to the output stream
        $output = fopen('php://output', 'w');
        fputcsv($output, $rows);
    }
}
```